# Next.js: Making changes to _app.tsx or _app.jsx doesn't update site. Custom pageExtensions setting

Tags: next.js

My `pages/_app.tsx` looks like this:

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";

import { MantineProvider } from "@mantine/core";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My description" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
      </Head>
      <MantineProvider
        withGlobalStyles
        withNormalizeCSS
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MantineProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

If I run the dev server (`npm run dev`) then everything works perfectly.

The problem is that if I make changes to my _app.tsx file then those changes are not reflected on the running application. Even if I insert intentional errors and try to break the site then the old version of _app.tsx still gets used.

If I build the app then the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the page extensions of my app, my next.config.js looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  output: "standalone",
  pageExtensions: ["page.tsx", "page.ts", "page.jsx", "page.js"],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I just needed to rename _app.tsx to _app.page.tsx